# Using a .txt file Resource in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Right now i have a line of code, in vb, that calls a text file, like this:

```
Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("data5.txt")
```

data5.txt is a resource in my application, however the application doesn't run because it can't find data5.txt. I'm pretty sure there is another code for finding a .txt file in the resource that i'm overlooking, but i can't seem to figure it out. So does anyone know of a simple fix for this? or maybe another whole new line of code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you added the file as a resource in the Project + Properties, Resources tab, you'll get its content by using My.Resources:

```
Dim content As String = My.Resources.data5
```

Click the arrow on the Add Resource button and select Add Existing File, select your data5.txt file.

Comment: Only if you add it to a .RexX file.

Comment: @SLaks only if you add it to the project like any normal .NET developer.  Its a lot easier to do it that way than to right-click on the file, set it to compile as a resource, then use your pointlessly complex method of getting a resource stream.

Comment: @WIll: Correct.  ResX files are much easier.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that the file is being compiled as an Embedded Resource.

Embedded Resources aren't files in the filesystem; that code will not work.

You need to call [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx), like this:

```
Dim fileText As String
Dim a As Assembly = GetType(SomeClass).Assembly
Using reader As New StreamReader(a.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.data5.txt"))
    fileText = reader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Comment: Why do people keep giving this answer?  Resources are exposed as strongly typed properties within `Properties.Resources`.

Comment: @Will: Only if you add it to a ResX file.

Comment: this didn't work for me because my `a.GetManifestResourceStream("RuleSyntax.txt")` returns a null stream. :((

Comment: After i solved my problem by using `a.GetManifestResourceNames()` i found that i need my project name + '.' before my filename. And now i see that SLaks did indeed have that in his code. So my bad. i just didn't understand what 'MyNamespace' was. Now i do. for others like me: add 3 items with periods between. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, go to project resources (My Project --> Resources), and drag-and-drop your file, say "myfile.txt", from the file system to the resourses page.
Then:

```
    Imports System.IO
    ...
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream(My.Resources.myfile)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)
    Dim s As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```