# Visual Studio 2012 resources path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Can you tell me how to read and write to txt files which are included in my project (resources) in Visual Studio 2012?
It's in resources but it seems that My.Resources doesn't work.

Comment: This might be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662623/using-a-txt-file-resource-in-vb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly

Comment: Now that I think about it txt wouldnt be good for this situtation because I am storing only one bolean value. Maybe Ill use registry key. Thank you very much