# Create an EXE that has files in it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, file, include, exe

I want to create an Exe that copies files to a directory on the c drive. 
So I want it to this.

I have added the files to the project.
And when I run the code.  It copies the file.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\direcotory1")

My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("file1", "c:\direcotry1\file1.dat")
```

The above code works, but...

After I compile if I move the exe out of the source directory, it doesn't work.  I have to leave the exe in the directory where the file is.

Phrased another way.  IF the exe is not in the directory it gets compiled into by Visual Studio.  Then it cannot find the file to copy.

I know people do this all the time, but I am not sure how to get them in there.
Properties are set to content, or embedded resource don't seem to make a difference.
Can anyone give me the piece I am missing?
Thanks
Dan

Comment: Please include your actual code. And when you say it doesn't work, what exactly happens and do you get any error messages.

Comment: It kicks out an error that it cannot find the file.  If I leave it in the source directory it works.  But I want it to be a stand alone file that I can push through SCCM.  It gives me an XML  slightly edited. 
-<WERReportMetadata>-<OSVersionInformation><WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion><Build>7601 Service Pack 1</Build><Product>(0x30): Windows 7 Professional</Product><BuildString>7601.18247.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532</BuildString><Revision>1130</Revision><Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor><Parameter8>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</Parameter8></Pro

Comment: Please edit your original post to include your code. Don't put it in a comment as it will be unreadable.

Comment: The exe basically is pulling the file from the source directory to copy it.  I don't want it to do that.  I want the file to be inside the exe, like a regular installer or something.      By the way. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Your file paths are spelled differently in your code, is that a typo? So when you move the .exe do you move the source file1 to the same place? When you set it to embedded resource which is what it sounds like you want, you have to reference it differently, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662623/using-a-txt-file-resource-in-vb)

Comment: Yes it was a typo.
 

First off, thanks to everyone for the help. 
Calling the string may have worked. What I did was found a different method.

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes ("C:\Folder\Filename, My.Resources.Filename)

And it worked.

Thanks Again .
I appreciate it.

Dan