# How to read .txt file in Resources

Tags: vb.net, winforms, io, text-files

Found a question already answering this? Please link it. I've not found anything.

How do I read a `.txt` file which I've placed into my `Resources` folder? The following code doesn't seem to find the file, even I know I've put it there. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
Using textreader As System.IO.TextReader = File.OpenText("Resources/map.txt")
```

This doesn't seem to work. Neither does:

```
Using textreader As System.IO.TextReader = File.OpenText(My.Resources.Map)
```

(`Map` is the name I've given it inside Visual Studio).

Alternatively, how would I find the program's `Debug/Resources` folder within the file system? What method do I use?

Any ideas what I can do to solve this? And when someone is using my program and wants to save the map file, where would be best programming practice to save it? (Since I can't put it in `Resources` because that's within the `.exe`). Just C:\Programs\ `A new folder just for my program`?

*N.B. VB.NET WinForms*

Comment: `strMap = My.Resources.Map`

Comment: I would create another folder to save these. Then you can use the Application.StartupPath to save and get the files...

Comment: @436f6465786572 could you please give an example answer? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a .txt file Resource in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662623/using-a-txt-file-resource-in-vb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question was best answer previously here:
[StackOverflow Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662623/using-a-txt-file-resource-in-vb)

```
Dim content As String = My.Resources.Map
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I needed to find a way to read text files within my program. This is what I found: 
 To add an existing text file as a resource
 Right Click on [project Name - your project] in solution explorer, then 
 Select Properties, then Resources,
 Then add the text file as an existing text file
(e.g. - you create myfile.txt and put it where you can find it)
 You can then read the text file as a stream of lines or as a single string

To read a resource text file as a stream of lines. This example will display the first line. You can then use streamreader code to access all the lines.

```
Dim lineA As String = String.Empty
Using reader As TextReader = New StringReader(My.Resources.myfile)
lineA = reader.ReadLine
MsgBox(lineA)
End Using
```

To read the resource text file as a single string
and display (e.g.) the first 5 characters

```
Dim LineB as String = MyResources.myfile
MsgBox(Mid(LineB,1,5))
```