# Why is Visual Studio 2013 not picking up my quotes for a textbox output (visual basic)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I made a program that shows a large amount of text in a rich text box in the latest version of Visual Studio on my home computer, and even though there are line breaks in the text, the program picks up everything that is within the quotes (eg. TextBox1.Text = "multiple paragraphs of writing", and everything within those quotes would turn red like output text is supposed to. Now, when I put the program on my school computer running Visual Studio 2013, it's only picking up the first line of text within the quotes and ignoring the other lines, and thus can not run because all of those lines of text are causing errors. Why is this happening?

```
Private Sub SnowyOwl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SNOtext.Text = "The regal Snowy Owl is one of the few birds that can get even non-birders to come out for a look. This largest (by weight) North American owl shows up irregularly in winter to hunt in windswept fields or dunes, a pale shape with catlike yellow eyes. They spend summers far north of the Arctic Circle hunting lemmings, ptarmigan, and other prey in 24-hour daylight. In years of lemming population booms they can raise double or triple the usual number of young.

MEASUREMENTS:

Length:
20.5–28 in
Wingspan:
49.6–57.1 in
Weight:
56.4–104.1 oz 

SIZE AND SHAPE:

- Snowy Owls are very large owls with smoothly rounded heads and no ear tufts, and are about the same size as a Great Horned Owl. The body is bulky, with dense feathering on the legs that makes the bird look wide at the base when sitting on the ground.

COLOR PATTERN:

- Snowy Owls are white birds with varying amounts of black or brown markings on the body and wings. On females this can be quite dense, giving the bird a salt-and-pepper look. Males tend to be paler and become whiter as they age. The eyes are yellow.

BEHAVIOR:

- Look for Snowy Owls sitting on or near the ground in wide-open areas. They often perch on rises such as the crests of dunes, or on fenceposts, telephone poles, and hay bales. When they fly they usually stay close to the ground.

MIGRATION:

 - Irruptive medium- to long-distance migrant. Snowy Owl migrations are extremely variable. Some North American Snowy Owls winter in southeastern Canada, the upper Great Lakes states, and New England just about every year. Winter numbers of Snowy Owls in the U.S. peak periodically, which may be attributed to lemming cycles farther north. During irruptive years, Snowy Owls can flush south throughout the lower 48 states, as far as south as Texas and Florida in extreme years.

FIND THIS BIRD:

- Unless you visit the high arctic, you’ll mainly be looking for Snowy Owls during winter in wide-open areas such as fields and shorelines. Scan snowy flat areas and be on the lookout for any irregularities in the snow. A lump or dirty patch could be a Snowy Owl facing away from you. Snowy Owls like to perch in conspicuous areas, so be sure to check high points like hay bales, fenceposts, telephone poles, buildings, or grain elevators. Also look for agitated birds—other raptors or gulls may swoop at a Snowy Owl sitting on a beach.

HABITAT:

- In winter, look for Snowy Owls along shorelines of lakes and the ocean, as well as on agricultural fields and airport lands. Snowy Owls breed in the treeless arctic tundra.


FUN FACTS: 
- The Snowy Owl can be found represented in cave paintings in Europe.

- In some years, some North American Snowy Owls remain on their breeding grounds year-round, while others migrate in winter to southern Canada and the northern half of the contiguous United States. In the northern plains, New York, and New England, Snowy Owls occur regularly in winter. Elsewhere, such as in the Pacific Northwest, the Midwest, and eastern Canada, Snowy Owls are irruptive, appearing only in some winters but not in others.

- Male Snowy Owls are barred with dark brown when they’re young and get whiter as they get older. Females keep some dark markings throughout their lives. Although the darkest males and the palest females are nearly alike in color, the whitest birds—including the ones that played Harry Potter’s Hedwig—are always males and the most heavily barred ones are always females.

- Unlike most owls, Snowy Owls are diurnal, extremely so. They’ll hunt at all hours during the continuous daylight of an Arctic summer. And they may eat more than 1,600 lemmings, their favorite meal, in a single year.

- Snowy Owl young may disperse remarkably far from their birthplace. From a single Snowy Owl nest on Victoria Island in the Canadian Arctic, one young bird went to Hudson Bay, one to southeastern Ontario, and one to the far eastern Russian coast.

- John James Audubon once saw a Snowy Owl lying at the edge of an ice hole, where it waited for fish and caught them using its feet.

-The oldest-known Snowy Owl was a female, and at least 23 years, 10 months old when she was recaptured in 2015 during banding operations in Montana. She had been banded in Massachusetts in 1992.

All readings provided above are courtesy of the Cornell Lab of Ornithology and AllAboutBirds.org."

    End Sub
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: alright it should be there

Comment: I guess that you have developed the program in VS2015, wherein VB allows multi-line string literals like that. VS2013 doesn't do that. I suggest putting the data into a file instead.

Comment: multi-line strings are only supported in [Visual Studio 2015/VB 14](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23620737/2882256) and above. You need to pu an `" &` at the end of each line. Anyway, I recommend to store the text in a Textfile and include it as Ressource in your project.

Comment: Okay but then how would I get that text file to display in the text box?

Comment: @onemillionwords17 [Using a .txt file Resource in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2662623/1115360)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: You could consider using an XML literal in earlier versions.